# How to curve text (or "bend" it) in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I curve text in a word? I was able to do in a previous version of word. I was able to bend any word.

I have tried the word art option and it allows only shadowing but not the option to curve a word.

Comment: What version of MS word are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010, highlight text and then select Word Art from the Drawing Tools / Format Tab and apply one of the Word Art text styles.

With text still selected, choose the Text Effect (bottom) button in the Word Styles section of the same tab and and then the Transform option on the drop-down menu.

[image: picture of dropdown menu for Transform effect]